# CKOperationGroup specify an order and chain operations

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am asking this question due to the lack of documentation on Apple's website. Is there any way to chain to CKOperation inside a CKOperationGroup to execute in order one after the other? In particular, I am interested in two CKModifyRecordsOperation that I need to execute one after the other.

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with the native CloudKit API, but you could pretty easily use promises/closures to achieve the same result.

Comment: Also, I think the whole point of a CKOperationGroup is that the operations execute "atomically." My guess is that there is no built-in way to make the operations execute sequentially using just one CKOperationGroup.

Comment: I will try with the NotificationCenter then guys. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I'm writing up a solution that uses `CKOperation.completionBlock`. I'll post it in a couple minutes. (it might not work though)

Comment: @Daniel I did that... It doesn't work. That's why I am creating a new notification name and emit it when the operation finishes

Comment: I actually abandoned completion block and used an OperationQueue instead. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `CKOperation.completionBlock`, how about using an `OperationQueue`? Here is what I came up with. It's completely untested, so let me know if it's useless.

```
class CKOperationQueue: NSObject {

    private var completionHandler: (() -> Void)?
    private var isExecuting = false
    private let operations: [CKOperation]
    private let queue: OperationQueue

    init(operations: [CKOperation]) {
        self.operations = operations
        queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.name = "CKOperationQueue"
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    }

    @discardableResult func execute() -> CKOperationQueue {
        guard !isExecuting else { return self }
        isExecuting = true

        queue.addOperations(operations, waitUntilFinished: false)
        queue.addOperation {
            self.completionHandler?()
        }

        return self
    }

    @discardableResult func onCompletion(_ handler: @escaping () -> Void) -> CKOperationQueue {
        self.completionHandler = handler
        return self
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice Idea. But I need the data from the previous operation. This way we solved the order but I need the data. In the end, I saved the array of records in a variable in the class and subscribed to a notification to get the previous operation data. Thanks a lot for the help.